# Правильный проброс исключения

Tags: python

Мне надо сделать так, чтобы в случае возникновении любой ошибки произошли некоторые одинаковые дейтсвия и некоторые специфические для определенной ошибки. Как-то так:

```
try:
    doing_some_actions
except SpecialErrorOne:
    doing_special_action1
    actions_for_all_errors
except SpecialErrorTwo:
    doing_special_action2
    actions_for_all_errors
except SpecialErrorThree:
    doing_special_action3
    actions_for_all_errors
```

Как лучше это сделать с минимальным повторением кода ?

Если сделать так, то исключение попадает на экран, минуя `SpecialError'ы`:

```
try:
    doing_some_actions
except Exception as ex:
    actions_for_error
    raise ex
except SpecialErrorOne:
    doing_special_action1
except SpecialErrorTwo:
    doing_special_action2
except SpecialErrorThree:
    doing_special_action3
```

Comment: Наилучшее решение может зависеть от конкретной задачи (можно в вопросе упомянуть что за исключения и что из себя actions_for_error, doing_special_actionN представляют) к примеру для OSError, можно if/elif использовать по errno, вместо except блоков. Чтобы запись в лог добавить в случае любой ошибки в заданном блоке кода, можно свой context manager и `with`-конструкцию использовать вокруг этого блока. `contextlib.ExitStack()` позволяет самые разнообразные стратегии реализовывать. Вариантов много.

Answer (score 3):

Можно наследовать базовый класс исключений [Exception](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html), в котором определить дейтсвия специфические для определенной ошибки, тогда нужен только один блок except, в котором будут одинаковые дейтсвия для ошибки. А doing_special_action вызывать исходя из имени исключения.

```
class SpecialErrorOne(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Call SpecialErrorOne')

class SpecialErrorTwo(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Call SpecialErrorTwo')

def actions_for_all_errors():
    print('Call actions_for_all_errors')

def doing_some_actions():
    raise SpecialErrorOne


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        doing_some_actions()
    except Exception as ex:
        if isinstance(ex, SpecialErrorOne):
            print('doing_special_action1')
        elif isinstance(ex, SpecialErrorTwo):
            print('doing_special_action2')

        actions_for_all_errors()
        raise
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать так:

```
try:
    doing_some_actions
    return
except SpecialErrorOne:
    doing_special_action1
except SpecialErrorTwo:
    doing_special_action2
except SpecialErrorThree:
    doing_special_action3
actions_for_all_errors
```

Comment: А если в одном из doing_special_action возникнет ошибка, которая пробросится наверх ?

Comment: Ну вообще правило хорошего тона избегать возможности появления ошибок в обработчиках ошибок. Оберните в try/except, если есть сомнения.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы использовал паттерн проектирования стратегия:

1. Класс `Action`, а от него уже унаследовал потомки `SpecialAction1`, `SpecialAction2`, ... , `SpecialActionN`. Общее поведение для всех реакций на разные ошибки можно написать прямо в `Action`
2. Далее блок `except` можно свести к одному: `except (Error1, Error2, Error3) as e`
3. В типе исключения добавить код ошибки с методом `error_no()`
4. Имея на руках п.3 можно порождать классы действий так: `Action.make(err.error_no()).run()`. Для этого нужно в базовом классе написать фабричный метод `make()` целью которого на основании кода ошибки создать класс реакции на ошибку

Comment: Питон, не Java—не стоит огород городить. Вы попробуйте целиком пример кода написать, чтобы осознать что это не самый лучший подход в Питоне. Даже похожий подход: обобщённые функции (functools.singledispatch) параметризированные по типу исключения (должны быть элегантнее предложенного в ответе подхода) были бы перебором в этом случае (хотя это от контекста зависит—автор вопроса не признаётся какой конкретно случай рассматривается, так что сложно сказать).

Comment: Да. @faoxis нужно уточнить его ситуаци. Но паттерн проектирования тут более чем уместен. Вариант конечно громоздкий. Не спорю. Но привычен и понятен! Мы же пишем код не для получения приза "Самый короткий код", а прежде всего для того, чтобы код был понятным не только нам самим, но и коллегам, даже тем которых мы еще не знаем. Использование `functools.singledispatch` не особо популярное среди python-программистов, уточнил это путем поиска использования по `github`

Comment: критерий не краткость кода, а его читаемость, простота, ясность, легкость в поддерживании и  расширении. То что singledispatch редко используется и я его предлагаю как улучшение над вашим решением должно подсказать глубину недостатков последнего.  Напишите полный пример  для решения, которое вы предлагаете, и сравните его с кодом из других ответов. Злоупотребление шаблонами проектирования—распространённая ошибка начинающих (из категории: know just enough to be dangerous—хуже чем  человека с нуля учить). То что вы сразу полный пример кода не привели уже само по себе говорит о качестве решения.